# Autocomplete first row wrong when selected second row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to ask something about jquery autocomplete, when I selected first row and fill it, it's work, but when I selected second row and fill with other word it's failed. It repeat to the word I fill at the first row.

here's my code

https://jsfiddle.net/yhzbjbcu/
https://youtu.be/hCtiTN8vm1w

my PHP

```
<?php
$buah = array('semangka','jeruk','apel','anggur');
for($x=0;$x<count($buah);$x++){
$row['value']= $buah[$x];
//buat array yang nantinya akan di konversi ke json
$row_set[] = $row;
}
//data hasil query yang dikirim kembali dalam format json
echo json_encode($row_set);
?>
```

I need the ID for input to database, its possible for me ?

Comment: I guess the reason why your autocomplete dont work on the second is because its has no id `cariBrg` second, in this case, use class for multiple elements

Comment: its work on the second row, but when I selected on the second row the first row change like second row [link](https://youtu.be/hCtiTN8vm1w)

Comment: Try look at this, use have to use `$(this)` updated your js https://jsfiddle.net/yhzbjbcu/1/

Comment: thank you @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: No problem, you are very welcome

Comment: Still problem , now the problem with the id, id on the first row change when I selected second row, I need the id because i want to input to mysql @Carsten